# magento2 google font not working

Tags: magento2, css, font-family

My default Head block is like this

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
         <link src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600,600italic,500italic,500" src_type="url" /> 
        <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
         <css src="css/custom-gw.css" />
        <css src="css/fetch_gw.css" />
        <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
        <css src="css/print.css" media="print" />


    </head>
</page>
```

it generates output like this in page source

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://localhost:8080/mac/pub/static/frontend/GWtheme/GW/en_US/css/styles-m.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://localhost:8080/mac/pub/static/frontend/GWtheme/GW/en_US/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://localhost:8080/mac/pub/static/frontend/GWtheme/GW/en_US/css/custom-gw.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://localhost:8080/mac/pub/static/frontend/GWtheme/GW/en_US/css/fetch_gw.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="http://localhost:8080/mac/pub/static/frontend/GWtheme/GW/en_US/css/styles-l.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="print" href="http://localhost:8080/anthony/pub/static/frontend/GWtheme/GW/en_US/css/print.css" />
<link  href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600,600italic,500italic,500" />
```

but when i apply Raleway font on body its not working
I can however see this in fire bug but its not appying

```
body {
    color: #6d4d3d;
    font-family: "Raleway",sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: Is the font-family declaration being overwritten by any other CSS?

Comment: Move your layout to current theme or module directory. `Ctrl+Shift+M` Clear browser cache and try to reload again

Comment: @Rakhi Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up your xml file like this:

> app/design/frontend/{{vendor}}/{{theme}}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" src_type="url" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
</page>
```